# Can PHP do this?

Tags: php, arrays

Can PHP do This.

I have multiple array like this :

```
$x[1][2][3] = 10;
$x[1][2][4] = 5;
$x[1][2][3] = 2;
```

When I'm using `print_r($x)` The result is :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

I want to do this :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

Maybe you know the function or script for get result that I wont.

Thank's for your help..

Answer (score 1):

Add ?

```
$x[1][2][3] = 10;
$x[1][2][4] = 5;
$x[1][2][3] = $x[1][2][3] + 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$x[1][2][3] += 10;
$x[1][2][4] += 5;
$x[1][2][3] += 2;
```

The problem is, if the key is not defined, you get a NOTICE. So you have to check before, wether the key exists for example with `if(!isset($x[1][2][3])) {$x[1][2][3] = 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is incrementing:

```
@$x[1][2][3] += 10;
@$x[1][2][4] += 5;
@$x[1][2][3] += 2;
```

`@` are for suppressing errors. It would be better and more explicit to initialize your indexes like so:

```
$x[1][2][3] = 0;
$x[1][2][4] = 0;

$x[1][2][3] += 10;
$x[1][2][4] += 5;
$x[1][2][3] += 2;
```